# AXIOS Get API Response in new window

Tags: reactjs, axios

I want to show my axios get response to new window is it possible? im using react as frontend and node as backend

Code:

```
 axios
    .get(
      `http://localhost:5000/files`
    )
    .then((res) => {
      this.setState({
       inferenceout: res.data , isLoading: false 
       
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a new window and write date in document

```
let newWin = window.open("about:blank", "Axios data", "width=400,height=400");
newWin.document.write(res);
```

Comment: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] this is the output i got when i run your code

Comment: @KarthikeyanM Use newWin.document.write(JSON.stringify(res))

Comment: it prints the overall json i want particular data(example: id only) like that . can you help me how to do this

Comment: You can pick wich data of response you want to send to new window

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `window.open('http://localhost:5000/files','_blank').focus()` if you want to work with fetched data from this url, you need to somehow (in query string for example) transfer states and all needed information to new window, and fetch data there